# How to enable and expose jmx beans programatically in jetty embedded server using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, jmx, embedded-jetty

I'm developing Spring Boot application with some REST controllers. I want to add JMX support and expose some Jetty's mbeans.

Tried to connect with jconsole but failed, so I guess JMX is disabled in this case by default.

The question is: how can I enable Jetty's JMX beans in Spring Boot application (with Jetty as embedded server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My solution is partially based on this [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jmx-chapter.html). In Spring Boot adding JMX support to Jetty is possible by adding custom server customizer. All You need to do is to add such bean:

```
@Bean
public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(@Value("${server.port:8080}") final String port) {

    JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =  new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(Integer.valueOf(port));
    factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {
        // Setup JMX
        MBeanContainer mbContainer=new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        server.addEventListener(mbContainer);
        server.addBean(mbContainer);

        server.addBean(Log.getLog());

    });
    return factory;
}
```